# How to replace Artifactory file "pattern" path dynamically in rtUpload in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'am trying to dynamically replace my zip file pattern in rtDownload in my declarative jenkinsfile but the value is not taken up by the function.

A zip file with a newer version is created and uploaded on JFrog with every build and I want to download a particular version in my local system.

I have defined "VERSION" in def VERSION and used it as -

```
  rtDownload (
                    serverId: 'Jfrog',
                    
                    spec: '''{
                        "files": [
                            {
                            "pattern": "<path>-<filname>${VERSION}.zip",
                            "target": "<path>-<filename>${VERSION}.zip",
                            "flat": "true"
                            }
                        ]
                    }'''
                )
```

But it does not replace my VERSION with the version I am providing through String parameter configured in the jenkins job.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In groovy single quote strings (`''`) and single quote multi line strings (`''' '''`) do not support string interpolation, only double quote strings support this.
You can read more info on string interpolation in groovy in the [Official Documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation).

So to fix it just use double quoted multi line string, that will enable the evaluation of your parameters:

```
rtDownload (
    serverId: 'Jfrog',               
    spec: """{
          "files": [
              {
                 "pattern": "<path>-<filname>${VERSION}.zip",
                 "target": "<path>-<filename>${VERSION}.zip",
                 "flat": "true"
               }
           ]
     }"""
)
```